# New GCP Cloud Build UI in not displaying the git tags in the RUN dropdown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Not able to see the Run Trigger button which was in the OLD Cloud RUN UI.

All the Git tags starting with "release" e.g.,***release-1.5.905.baf134e*** are not matching in the Source Tag
[image]

Screenshot attached for OLD Cloud Build UI:
[image]

In the new Cloud Build UI RUN button does not show the list of Tags we have created.
Screenshot attached for NEW Cloud Build UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the list of tags in the new UI of Cloud Build, click the `RUN` button and you will see the available tags in the panel that appears.

I also attached a screenshot:

[image: 1]

---

**Update**

After you update your question, I tried to reproduce your use case again.

- I created two new releases and tagged them as `release-1.0` and `release-1.5`.
- Then I created a trigger to `Push new tag`, with the RegEx `.*release*`.
- Clicking `RUN` on the trigger that I created, the *Run trigger* panel appears and shows the tags matching the REGEX. See the attached screenshot below:

[image: 2]

I would suggest you to try creating a new trigger and see how this works for you and also make sure that the trigger is pointing to the right repository. If the repository is not right, then the RegEx won't match any tags. If your issue is not resolved, you may consider reporting this through the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Problem is its not matching the regex we have for the TAGs. But with the OLD UI the same regex was working

Comment: could you update your question with the actual issue, sharing the regex that is not working anymore?

Comment: Thanks! I tried the same with the new trigger, still issue exist

Comment: Did you make sure that you target the right repository? If this still doesn't work with you, you report this issue through [Google's issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)